# Keras conversion in Pytorch

Tags: keras, pytorch, computer-vision

I have the following code in keras:

```
# load all images in a directory into memory
def load_images(path, size=(256,512)):
    src_list, tar_list = list(), list()
    # enumerate filenames in directory, assume all are images
    for filename in listdir(path):
        # load and resize the image
        pixels = load_img(path + filename, target_size=size)
        # convert to numpy array
        pixels = img_to_array(pixels)
        # split into satellite and map
        sat_img, map_img = pixels[:, :256], pixels[:, 256:]
        src_list.append(sat_img)
        tar_list.append(map_img)
    return [asarray(src_list), asarray(tar_list)]
```

I would like to convert it to pytorch, but I don't know much about it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have anything to change but the very last line:

```
return [torch.stack(src_list), torch.stack(tar_list)]
```

Comment: For example, load_img and img_to_array are keras functions and must be changed

Comment: You can use `torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor` as an alternative.